# In Perl/Moose, how do you create a static variable in a parent class that can be accessed from subclasses?

Tags: perl, static, moose

I want to define a "registry" hash in the base class that all subclasses can read and write to, how do I accomplish this with Moose/Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an implementation with plain Perl OO-style.

You have two classes, `BaseClass` with global variable `$REGISTRY`, and `DerivedClass` which inherits from `BaseClass`.
`$REGISTRY` is readable and writable from any class instance via `registry()` method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;

package BaseClass;

our $REGISTRY = {};

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub registry {
    my $self = shift;
    return $REGISTRY;
}

package DerivedClass;

push our @ISA, 'BaseClass';

package main;

my $base    = BaseClass->new;
$base->registry->{ alpha } = 1;

my $derived = DerivedClass->new;
$derived->registry->{ beta } = 2;

say $_, ' -> ', $base->registry->{ $_ } foreach keys %{ $base->registry };
```

If you run this program you get:

```
alpha -> 1
beta -> 2
```

If you prefer an all-Moose solution you should try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;

package BaseClass;
use Moose;

our $_REGISTRY = {};
has '_REGISTRY' => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'HashRef',
    default => sub { return $_REGISTRY }
);

sub registry {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->_REGISTRY;
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
no Moose;

package DerivedClass;
use Moose;

use base 'BaseClass';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
no Moose;

package main;

my $base    = BaseClass->new;
$base->registry->{ alpha } = 1;

my $derived = DerivedClass->new;
$derived->registry->{ beta } = 2;

say $_, ' -> ', $base->registry->{ $_ } foreach keys %{ $base->registry };
```

It yields the same result of the OO Perl program.
Note how the `_REGISTRY` attribute is defined. Moose doesn't like refs as default values: `default => {}` is forbidden, you have to wrap any reference as a return value in an anonymous subroutine.

Comment: Moose in fact blocks `default => {}` to prevent this problem being the default. When default were to take a bare ref, every instance would share the same ref. With default evaluating a code reference, a new ref can be created every time. In this case you're subverting that and returning the same ref every time.

Answer (score 5):

How about just implement it as a method:

```
package BaseClass;

my $hash = {};
sub registry { $hash };
```

Sub-classes just use `$self->registry->{$key}` to access values and `$self->registry->{$key} = $value` to set them.

Comment: when I tried to do this, the subclasses were creating their own version of the variable... is there some SUPER:: descoping I should use?

Comment: What do you have going on in your sub-classes? My solution is essentially the same as using a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

[MooseX::ClassAttribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aClassAttribute)

Comment: @nodebunny, There's no such thing as MooseX. Do you mean MooseX::ClassAttribute? Why can't you use it?

Comment: @nodebunny, Why not? Why can you install Perl code from StackOverflow but not from CPAN? Would it help if I copy MooseX::ClassAttribute to StackOverflow?

Comment: because its a shared host and id have to wait for them to install it for everyone

Comment: @nodebunny, No, you don't need any special permissions. You can install modules to any directory.

Comment: @nodebunny: Have a look at [cgipan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgipan/) to install modules in your accessible directories. No need to ask an admin.